# can't create user in vtiger by API

Tags: php, python, api, vtiger, vtigercrm

I can't create user in vTiger 7 programmatically. I am using python and get the following error in response:

```
{u'error': {u'code': u'ACCESS_DENIED',
  u'message': u'Permission to perform the operation is denied for id'},
 u'success': False}
```

I guess something wrong with id which I send to server.

This is my code:

```
url='http://owl24.ru/webservice.php/'
username='weblanss'
values = {'operation':'getchallenge','username': username }
data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request('%s?%s' % (url,data))
response = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
token = json.loads(response)['result']['token']
key = md5(token + accessKey)
tokenizedAccessKey = key.hexdigest()
values['accessKey'] = tokenizedAccessKey
values['operation']  = 'login'
data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()

values['sessionName'] = json.loads(response)['result']['sessionName']
values['userId'] =json.loads(response)['result']['userId']
values['operation'] = 'create'
values['elementType'] = 'Users'
data = urllib.urlencode(values)

dic = collections.OrderedDict([,('userId','19x12'),
        ('lastname', 'test_user2'),
('user_name','nam3'),('user_password','user_password'),('confirm_password','user_password'),('roleid','H1')])
dic = json.dumps(dic)
values['element']=dic
data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
response = json.loads(response.read())
```

I had tried a lot of different id, for example send my assigned id which I got from server. My role in vtiger allows me to create users. Maybe I need to change id. Also, I had successfully login and get success in response. I can create contact without any trouble, but I can't create user. I always get -Permission to perform the operation is denied for id'. Maybe I should send something special in assigned_id field or userId?

Comment: I don't think the api allows USERS creation.

Comment: is there any way to create user programmatically?

Comment: also ,then i try to create account i get  - {u'code': u'ACCESS_DENIED',
  u'message': u'Permission to perform the operation is denied'},
 u'success': False}

Comment: Did you solve it? Does the REST api allow User creation? @RubenEstrada

Comment: You would have to look at the code, but I'm almost certain that function is not permitted. You would need to create your own custom function as a service that allows user creation.

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65722501/i-cant-make-a-basic-http-authentication-using-php/66896132#66896132) to how to use the vTiger 7.2 API.

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65722501/i-cant-make-a-basic-http-authentication-using-php/66896132#66896132) on how to use the vTiger 7.2 API.

Answer (score -1):

**Actual process to get API call** 
1) First of all you need to get GetChallengeResult (challenge token)
2) You account on vtiger already have userAccessKey.
3) Now you have to concatenate these both key and then you have to hash this concatenated string into MD5
4) And to make an api call you need to pass "sessionName"=>$sessionId, "operation"=>'create' where sessionName is the one that you get from vtiger when you make success login using that generated key (md5).

I have written a HTTP client for vtiger 7 to make API calls but using PHP not Python. I can post that code if you  want. But try above steps first on your own using python.

I used this [Vtiger Link](https://wiki.vtiger.com/index.php/Webservices_tutorials) to create HTTP client Application to make API calls vtiger 7. As we know the vtiger API is not fully RESTful API and not using oAuth spec as intended its difficult make complex API calls.

Comment: Oh , thanks for your answer .I have already done all these steps. I Just had not included it to my description , so i edit my question. Please post your code , because i still cant get  -Permission to perform the operation is denied for id

Comment: Problem is my code is not with me right now, its on my office desktop PC. Let me see if that PC is turned on. I will see your updated post and see whats missing, give me a chance.