# I can't make a basic http authentication using PHP

Tags: php, api, rest, http, vtiger

I have a work to do and I need to login to the webpage, and extract content from it.
**The query has to be made of a username and an access key.**
The problem is that I don't really know how to make a query with thos 2 elements, and in PHP.
So, I have found this code have this code :

```
$ak =  "accesskey";

$username = 'admin';
$password = '123';
$remote_url = 'http://192.168.1.78/index.php';

// Create a stream
$opts = array(
    'http'=>array(
        'method'=>"GET",
        'header' => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$username:$ak")
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

// Open the file using the HTTP headers set above
$file = file_get_contents($remote_url, false, $context);

print($file);
```

But the output is simply the Webpage code, from the `<!DOCTYPE html><html>` to `</html>`

According to the webpage REST API, the result that I need to get is this :

```
{
    success: true,
    result: json_result
}
```

Any idea why it doesn't work ?

PS : here is the API documentation : https://www.vtiger.com/docs/rest-api-for-vtiger#/Authentication

Comment: We'll need to see the index.php code before we can comment on why it's doing that

Comment: If the server isn't returning the data you expect then that sounds like something you'd need to investigate on the server...

Comment: It must be said though that of all the endpoints mentioned in that documentation link you've provided, none of them ends with `index.php`. Are you sure you're using it correctly? It suggests URLS ending with things like `endpoint/me` .

Comment: `192.168.1.78` belongs to private network range 192.168.0.0/16 so it isn't a public IP address. Are you knowingly hosting the API server yourself?

Comment: @ADyson, so technically it's vtiger's webpage, I did not do this

Comment: @edoode moreoever the documentation appears to be for the vtiger _cloud_ edition. Not for some self-hosted web page. Again, are you sure you're looking at documentation which relates to the thing you're actually using?

Comment: @ADyson honestly, I really don't not what does endpoint/me means, I was looking for other responses before

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, yes, I am hosting the server by myself

Comment: `endpoint/me` is the end of a URL. e.g. if your CRM instance was hosted at `https://your_instance.odx.vtiger.com/restapi/v1/vtiger/default` (as per the example in the docs) then to access the "me" data, you'd send a request to `https://your_instance.odx.vtiger.com/restapi/v1/vtiger/default/me`

Comment: That documentation doesn't mention anything about self-hosting. It's all about the cloud instance.

Comment: about the question that above, thanks for the explaination of endpoint/me, it really helps me understand what's going on ! for your previous question, Its the only API documentation that I found for Vtiger

Comment: @ADyson, the problem is that for my work, its going to be a hosted webserver, so I have to do it that way

Comment: Ok but, the self-hosted open-source product, vs the cloud CRM, that's basically a different product, which either (it's unclear from a quick google - I'm not previously familiar with vtiger specifically) has a different API, or doesn't have any API at all. If you can't find out from the product documentation then you should perhaps ask on their specialist forums.

Comment: @ADyson I haven't mentionned it but the CRM is running on Virtualbox, Ubuntu20.4. It counts as a cloud platform right ?

Comment: No, not at all. All you've done is virtualise it on your own server. Vtiger's cloud CRM is a product that they host on _their_ servers (in a cloud data centre, probably) - it's software-as-a-service (SAAS), if you've heard that term before. You just pay a fee to open an account, you don't have to install anything. It has enhancements in it beyond what is available in the downloadable open-source edition. Read https://www.vtiger.com/open-source-vs-cloud/

Comment: P.S. I think I found something that might be useful for you... there is separate documentation for the open-source edition (the home page of that is here: https://community.vtiger.com/help/) and within it is some documentation about its API: https://community.vtiger.com/help/vtigercrm/developers/third-party-app-integration.html . I never really even heard of vtiger before you posted this question, but it's amazing what you can find with a few minutes of googling and reading the website.

Comment: Thanks for the lniks, But I already saw those pages, the problem is that I don't really code in PHP, so any informations on this documentation is "irrelevant" to me, I can't really make some with code it knowing that I don't really code in php

Comment: The API documentation link I gave you doesn't require any knowledge of PHP. You can make requests to it from anything. But you were writing PHP code in your question above, so...if you don't know PHP why don't you write it some language you do understand?

Answer (score 0):

The [vTiger API](https://community.vtiger.com/help/vtigercrm/developers/third-party-app-integration.html) (in 7.2 at least) has an odd combination of parameter and form POST payloads.  Here is the Python script I used to get started.  Note that it uses `param` in the `getchallenge` hit but `data` in the `login` hit:

```
import requests
from hashlib import md5
import urllib3

urllib3.disable_warnings()  # shut up whining about that security stuff

encoding = 'ascii'
userName = 'Michael'
userToken = (access key from my preferences page)
APIURL='https://our.crm.instance/webservice.php'

session = requests.Session()

def getSession(session, name, token):

    response = session.get(APIURL, params={'operation':'getchallenge', 'username':userName}, verify=False)

    token_key = response.json()['result']['token']

    combined = token_key + userToken

    accessKey = md5(combined.encode(encoding)).hexdigest()

    response1 = session.post(APIURL,
            data={'operation':'login', 'username':userName, 'accessKey':accessKey},
            verify=False)
    return response1.json()['result']['sessionName']

sessionToken = getSession(session, userName, userToken)

types = session.get(APIURL, params={'operation':'listtypes', 'sessionName':sessionToken})
print(types.json())
```